# Pass html string in controller and put into .html (angular js)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-bindings, angularjs-sce

I have a problem. Call my button "off" or "on" that I needed. If active status in json is 1 then button off is showing in html, so instead. But I have tried with

> ng-bind-html

Still not working, any solution for me ? Thanks

This is my code :

**Controller**

```
if(item.active === 1){
    html_button = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> On</button>';

}else{
   console.log(1);
    html_button = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i> Off</button>';
}

$scope.getButtonOnOff = function(html_button) {

    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_button);

};
```

**Html**

```
<span ng-if="data.active === 1">
            <button ng-show="data.active" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="FiturThread(data)"><i class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i> Off</button>
            <button ng-hide="data.active" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="FiturThread(data)"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> On</button>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="data.active === 0">
            <button ng-show="data.active" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="FiturThread(data)"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> On</button>
            <button ng-hide="data.active" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="FiturThread(data)"><i class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i> Off</button>
        </span>
```

Comment: look closely at your html and see that you in essence have like 90% of shared code between the active and inactive button, and this change is driven by a state on an object you are binding to. Do you really think that rewriting the full button code and binding to html is the best option? Other than writing the html out and making the changes in the text css classes, you could also make a directive that takes the state, which could be reused throughout your application. There is absolutely no need here to use `ng-bind-html`

Comment: Is there any particular reason why cant you use [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try **angular** way

```
<td width="20%">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getData(data)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
        <button ng-show="item.active" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> On</button>
        <button ng-hide="item.active" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i> Off</button>
</td>
```

Comment: I agree that this is a much better solution. You can also use the [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive if you dont want your nodes to populate the DOM when they are not active.

Comment: and also dont forget to put the `item` on `$scope`

Comment: If you have singular element use `ngIf` directive and if you want to toggle between two elements or more elements use `ngShow` and `ngHide` so that the `DOM` does not get destructed, when we add custom directives we will get the problems

Comment: How "item.active" can read my code if item.active === 1 or item.active == 0 ?

Comment: if `item.active === 1` then button `on` is shown and `off` is hidden, and when `item.active === 0` button `on` hidden and `off` will be shown.

Comment: So, I put if in controller or view ?

Comment: <span ng-if="data.active === 1">
                <button ng-show="data.active" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="FiturThread(data)"><i class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i> Off</button>
                <button ng-hide="data.active" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="FiturThread(data)"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> On</button>
            </span>

Comment: `<span> <button ng-show="data.active" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="FiturThread(data)"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> On</button> <button ng-hide="data.active" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="FiturThread(data)"><i class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i> Off</button> </span>` i changed the code,what it does is it shows `on` button when `isactive===1` and `off` button when `isactive===0` is that what you want right?

Comment: you have to put it in view

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle and tell me what you want to do, so that i can solve

Comment: why do you created two `span` elements one is enough to show hide buttons, have you not seen my above comment with code

Comment: do this `{{data.active}}` just below those span and tell me what you got the value on page load, why you have `item.active` in controller and `data.active` in html you provided

Comment: Alright, now its working and expected as I want. Thank you so much, im sorry , im bother you

Comment: No problem, but you have to provide extra info/code when you ask so that every one understand what you want to achieve and you will solve the problem very quickly